How to test dart record patterns?
I have a function:
(int,double?) eva(String);
I can test it with:
expect(eva("something"), (4,10));
// or
expect(eva("something").$1, isNonZero);
expect(eva("something").$2, 10);

but not as
expect(eva("something"), (isNonZero,10) );

Any tips are welcome.
EDIT:
I have a workaround: the function eva() should return a list, and so we can write:
expect(eva("something"), [isNonZero,10]);


your workaround loses typesafety though.

@RandalSchwartz Yes, but as my eva() function is already for test purposes only, I can embed type safety in it.

From the expect documentation, the second argument should either be a matcher or a value. If it is a value, "it will be wrapped in an equals matcher", so passing a record as the second argument will only ever test for equality.
Edit:
As pointed out by @jamesdin and confirmed by the matcher library equals function documentation, "For Iterables and Maps, [an equals matcher] will recursively match the elements."
End edit
I would recommend creating a CustomMatcher that can analyze nested matchers within a record. This would let you do something like
expect(eva("something"), MyRecordMatcher( (isNonZero, 10) ));.
Edit:
Another way to do this without changing eva to return a list is to convert the record to a list at the time of the test. There is no built-in way to do this, so you would have to make that conversion function yourself, but it would let you do something like
expect(recordToList(eva("something")), [isNonZero,10]);.
In my opinion this is less elegant and it adds a point of failure to getting the "actual" value, but it should work.

Thanks. But a list is a 'value', too.  And it's surprising that it works that way, because lists are only equal to themselves, by default. But here the item-by-item comparison works.

@kantal The equals Matcher can iterate over a List or other containers.  A Record is not iterable; there is no way to generically do  element-wise operations on them for arbitrary Records.

@jamesdlin You'r right.
